# while using slideToggle, how to make all other divs slide back up?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am building my portfolio site using bootstrap. I need to add project details under the images on my portfolio. It does toggle up and down when i click on the image but if I click on another image, the first div stays visible. How do i make all other visible "project-detail" divs slide back up when the user clicks on another image with slideToggle?

```js
$('div.project-detail').hide();

$('img.doug').click(function() {
  $('#dougDet').slideToggle();
});

$('img.ambe').click(function() {
  $('#ambeDet').slideToggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="workBlock" class="portfolio-block fixed-bg dark-bg">
  <div class="row">
    <img src="assets/portfolio/doug-fir-logo-for-instagran.jpg" alt="Doug Fir Digital Logo" class="portfolio-half doug">
    <img src="assets/portfolio/AmbeCreations-logo.jpg" alt="Ambe creations logo" class="portfolio-half ambe">
  </div>
  <div class="project-detail" id="dougDet">
    <p>doug</p>
    <p>doug</p>
    <p>doug</p>
    <p>doug</p>
    <p>doug</p>
  </div>
  <div class="project-detail" id="ambeDet">
    <p>ambe</p>
    <p>ambe</p>
    <p>ambe</p>
    <p>ambe</p>
    <p>ambe</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve what you need by calling `slideUp()` on the other `.project-detail` elements and toggling the targeted one.

Also note that you can DRY up your code by using a single event handler on all the `.portfolio-half` elements and using a `data-*` attribute to differentiate between them, something like this:

```js
$('img.portfolio-half').click(function() {
  var $target = $($(this).data('target')).slideToggle();
  $('.project-detail').not($target).slideUp();
});
```

```css
div.project-detail { display: none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="workBlock" class="portfolio-block fixed-bg dark-bg">
  <div class="row">
    <img src="assets/portfolio/doug-fir-logo-for-instagran.jpg" alt="Doug Fir Digital Logo" class="portfolio-half doug" data-target="#dougDet">
    <img src="assets/portfolio/AmbeCreations-logo.jpg" alt="Ambe creations logo" class="portfolio-half ambe" data-target="#ambeDet">
  </div>
  <div class="project-detail" id="dougDet">
    <p>doug</p>
    <p>doug</p>
    <p>doug</p>
    <p>doug</p>
    <p>doug</p>
  </div>
  <div class="project-detail" id="ambeDet">
    <p>ambe</p>
    <p>ambe</p>
    <p>ambe</p>
    <p>ambe</p>
    <p>ambe</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Also note that I moved the hiding of the `.project-detail` elements to CSS to avoid the FOUC on load of the JS.

Comment: Your code toggles before sliding up, and your post says the opposite.

Comment: If you change the order of operations the code doesn't work, try showing and hiding the same item.